# How to copy files from remote server to local machine?

Tags: ssh, pdf, latex

I use `ssh mylogin@server` to connect to a remote server... I am wondering how to copy the whole files from there to my local machine...

One reason to do this, is that, I could not compile a latex file on the server, there is an error: `! LaTeX Error: File tikz.sty not found.` I guess this error will disappear if I compile the same file on my local machine.

Another reason is that it seems that there are not too many tools on the server, for example, I can not open a `pdf` by `evince`, which is doable on my local machine.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree eith Engels Peralta, this is the simplest way.

From Nautilus go to `File -> Connect to Server...`

Change type to SSH, then enter your SSH details and credentials.

Now it should show up in your file system pane on the left.

You can then browse, copy or whatever. Note that you do not need to have an ssh session active before connecting, this will initiate the SSH session. Be sure to create a bookmark so you can access from the bookmark menu. I use the same method to connect to a test webserver.

Comment: the more i use linux, the more i get amazed! - a windows user

Answer (score 3):

You can use nautilus for this just go to connect to server and then select ssh fill what is needed to connect then you can drag and drop to your local machine.

Comment: sftp is the underlying protocol. It is built into the ssh protocol, so if you can ssh in, you can also use sftp.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the remote files as if they were on your machine with [SSHFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS). Install the [sshfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sshfs) package (`sudo apt-get install sshfs`). Make sure you are in the `fuse` group (see the [SSHFS page on the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)). Run

```
mkdir ~/server
sshfs mylogin@server: ~/server
cd ~/server/docs/stuff
pdflatex mypaper.tex
evince mypaper.pdf
```

The files under `~/server` are those of the remote machine, and you can work with all your applications on the local machine.